# Update IBM Connections Community files

Tags: ibm-connections

I am trying to write a simple HTTP PUT command to update a file in an IBM Connections community. I find the syntax of creating a file in [a community on IBM Connections wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_community_files_ic50&content=apicontent). But couldn't locate any information on how to update an existing community file.

To be specific, I know how to update the file in my own collection:

```
PUT /files/basic/api/myuserlibrary/document/f7064edd-477a-44b7-85a3-d35276e4a362/media

Content-Type=application/binary
X-Update-Nonce=myNonce
Filename=myFile
```

But couldn't quite figure out how to do similar operation for an existing file in community.

NOTE: I am writing the code in VBA within Excel, using the XMLHTTP reference library to send the HTTP request to the server.

Comment: switch the method to a POST and use X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE=PUT

Comment: Thanks @PaulBastide. Could you be more specific? Besides using POST instead of PUT, what would be the URL to send the POST?

Comment: same url... just add another header

Comment: Paul, I am sorry but I still couldn't quite figure it out. The URL I listed above was for another personal file and not in a community file. How do I figure out the URL for the community file that I want to update?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984433/ibm-connections-api-uploading-files-in-a-community-and-getting-nonce-widget