# IBM Connections API - Uploading files in a community and getting nonce - Widget

Tags: ibm-connections

There is a requirement to upload a file into a Community from an widget ( instead of going to files sections within a community and upload )

1. Can we upload files from an widget into a Community Files Section. I found this article [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/75320055-580c-4102-9574-af754853594b/entry/ibm_connections_files_api_upload_file_tutorial?lang=en) which talks about uploading files, but not under Community section. Is uploading files through community section possible ? Any reference would help
2. How do we get a Nonce in a widget ? Do we still need to pass authentication parameters, or can use those from the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Adding_a_file_using_a_multipart_POST_ic50&content=apicontent 
* however you 
you want to post this url pattern 
https://{serverUrl}/files/basic/api/communitylibrary/{communityUuid}/feed

For the nonce 
if you are in an iWidget specifically, you can look at the csrf_token and use that in the X-Update-Nonce header.

However, there is no guarantee that it remains named csrf_token.  You should use http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_a_cryptographic_key_ic50&content=apicontent

Comment: Can we call the "/files/basic/api/nonce" every time using xhr.get, before we upload the file. Would that be advisable. Also since the community is moderated, passing of username/password would not be required

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best approach, and yes you are correct, you share the context and session cookies